# Can't make placeholder and input field's border disappear on focus - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi there I'm playing around with this name plate calculator as I'm lerning JS. Basically you insert your name and every letter costs 5 dollars.

When I insert an invalid name, a placeholder pops out ('Please insert a valid name') and a red border around the input field. So far so good.

**What I want to do is:**

-once I inserted an invalid name, when I click again on the input field I want the placeholder and the border to disappear but **I don't know** how to say *'is focused'* in JS. I tried `personName = document.activeElement` but it's not working.

**Here the JS code**

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.button')
let cost = document.querySelector('.cost')
let yourPlate = document.querySelector('.yourplate')
let refresh = document.querySelector('.refresh')


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let personName = document.querySelector('.input').value;

  yourPlate.classList.add('show');
  cost.innerText = personName.trim().length * 5;

  if(personName == '' || personName.length < 2) {
    document.querySelector('.input').style.border = '2px solid red'
document.querySelector('.input').value = ''
    document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = 'Please insert a valid name'
    yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  }

})

refresh.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
  yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  document.querySelector('.input').style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = ''
})
```

**And HERE the snippet**

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.button')
let cost = document.querySelector('.cost')
let yourPlate = document.querySelector('.yourplate')
let refresh = document.querySelector('.refresh')


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let personName = document.querySelector('.input').value;

  yourPlate.classList.add('show');
  cost.innerText = personName.trim().length * 5;

  if(personName == '' || personName.length < 2) {
    document.querySelector('.input').style.border = '2px solid red';
    document.querySelector('.input').value = ''
    document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = 'Please insert a valid name'
    yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  }

})

refresh.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
  yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  document.querySelector('.input').style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = ''
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: verdana;
}

body {
  background: url('utah2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(20,0,0,.5);
}

.container {
  height: 55vh;
  min-width: 90vw;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: url('utah.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
}

.calculate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.yourplate {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  display: none;
}

.yourplate.show {
  display: block;
}

.cost {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;
}

.input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}

.button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.refresh {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
  background: rgba(0,147,255,0.5);
  outline: none;
}

.dot1, .dot2, .dot3, .dot4 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(150,150,150,.7), rgba(50,50,50));
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black, 0 0 10px rgb(183, 65, 14);
}

.dot1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot2 {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.dot3 {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot4 {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Plate Cost</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot2"></div>
    <div class="dot3"></div>
    <div class="dot4"></div>
    <h1>PLATE CALCULATOR</h1>
    <h3>Enter your name and calculate the cost</h3>
    <p class="yourplate">Your plate costs <span class="cost"></span> dollars</p>
    <div class="calculate">
      <input type="text" class="input"><br>
      <button type="submit"  class="button">Calculate</button>
      <button class="refresh">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional handler for `focus` event.

```
document.querySelector('.input').addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  event.target.style.border = 'none';
  event.target.placeholder = '';
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a `onKeyUp` funtion on your input field and check after every single input if input is valid.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the `focus` event for that like so:

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.button');
let cost = document.querySelector('.cost');
let yourPlate = document.querySelector('.yourplate');
let refresh = document.querySelector('.refresh');
let input = document.querySelector('.input');

const refreshInputField = () => {
  input.value = '';
  yourPlate.classList.remove('show');
  input.style.border = 'none';
  input.placeholder = '';
}

input.addEventListener('focus', refreshInputField);

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let personName = document.querySelector('.input').value;

  yourPlate.classList.add('show');
  cost.innerText = personName.trim().length * 5;

  if(personName == '' || personName.length < 2) {
    input.style.border = '2px solid red';
    input.value = ''
    input.placeholder = 'Please insert a valid name'
    yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  }

})

refresh.addEventListener('click', refreshInputField)
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: verdana;
}

body {
  background: url('utah2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(20,0,0,.5);
}

.container {
  height: 55vh;
  min-width: 90vw;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: url('utah.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
}

.calculate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.yourplate {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  display: none;
}

.yourplate.show {
  display: block;
}

.cost {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;
}

.input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}

.button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.refresh {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
  background: rgba(0,147,255,0.5);
  outline: none;
}

.dot1, .dot2, .dot3, .dot4 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(150,150,150,.7), rgba(50,50,50));
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black, 0 0 10px rgb(183, 65, 14);
}

.dot1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot2 {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.dot3 {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot4 {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Plate Cost</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot2"></div>
    <div class="dot3"></div>
    <div class="dot4"></div>
    <h1>PLATE CALCULATOR</h1>
    <h3>Enter your name and calculate the cost</h3>
    <p class="yourplate">Your plate costs <span class="cost"></span> dollars</p>
    <div class="calculate">
      <input type="text" class="input"><br>
      <button type="submit"  class="button">Calculate</button>
      <button class="refresh">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### Further reading

[focus event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not know what event to use just go and read the event list and find one suitable for you: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp
I suggest using `onfocus`

```
document.querySelector('input.input').onfocus = function(e){console.log(true)
this.style.border = 'none'};
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('.button')
let cost = document.querySelector('.cost')
let yourPlate = document.querySelector('.yourplate')
let refresh = document.querySelector('.refresh')


btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let personName = document.querySelector('.input').value;

  yourPlate.classList.add('show');
  cost.innerText = personName.trim().length * 5;

  if(personName == '' || personName.length < 2) {
    document.querySelector('.input').style.border = '2px solid red';
    document.querySelector('.input').value = ''
    document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = 'Please insert a valid name'
    yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  }

})

refresh.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  document.querySelector('.input').value = '';
  yourPlate.classList.remove('show')
  document.querySelector('.input').style.border = 'none'
  document.querySelector('.input').placeholder = ''
})

document.querySelector('input.input').onfocus = function(e){console.log(true)
this.style.border = 'none'};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: verdana;
}

body {
  background: url('utah2.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  background-blend-mode: darken;
}

.body {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(20,0,0,.5);
}

.container {
  height: 55vh;
  min-width: 90vw;
  padding: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: url('utah.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: fixed;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px black;
}

.calculate {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}

.yourplate {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 43%;
  display: none;
}

.yourplate.show {
  display: block;
}

.cost {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px black, 0 0 10px black;
  font-size: 1.8em;
}

h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  top:-25px;
}

.input {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 2em;
  width: 70%;
}

.button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}

.refresh {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  outline: none;
  font-size: .9em;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.button:active {
  transform: scale(.95);
  background: rgba(0,147,255,0.5);
  outline: none;
}

.dot1, .dot2, .dot3, .dot4 {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background: radial-gradient(rgba(150,150,150,.7), rgba(50,50,50));
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black, 0 0 10px rgb(183, 65, 14);
}

.dot1 {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot2 {
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.dot3 {
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

.dot4 {
  top: 20px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Plate Cost</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="body"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="dot1"></div>
    <div class="dot2"></div>
    <div class="dot3"></div>
    <div class="dot4"></div>
    <h1>PLATE CALCULATOR</h1>
    <h3>Enter your name and calculate the cost</h3>
    <p class="yourplate">Your plate costs <span class="cost"></span> dollars</p>
    <div class="calculate">
      <input type="text" class="input"><br>
      <button type="submit"  class="button">Calculate</button>
      <button class="refresh">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```